# Horde/ingo filter with dovecot sieve not matching From

Tags: dovecot, sieve, sieve-rules

I have the following sieve script (generated by Horde's ingo program):

```
if address :all :comparator "i;ascii-casemap" :contains "From" "Apotheke"  {
    discard;
    stop;
}
```

But it just won't match my emails. For example:

```
[...]
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; s=root; d=studio24mw.com;
 h=From:Subject:To:Content-Type:MIME-Version:Date:Message-ID;
 i=firewall@studio24mw.com;
 bh=vLpX7dkYT5Q4Pa27lzI7l2QbOYaZ6KqVK8qoW3XtNXI=;
 b=VIXKBd3YeXmCYVVCe/3XhlEwy/7WKjIS9PsG0c63d8P08aVkNOj0mZneGF8o2QibLFJYWQ7Xg1Pj
   ckPVTrE9+PMpcUhGu40QNjl1vgSoV/CbnrY3MB3rVmmjqqW5s5wvRB1EXpCRP3fwu6BAUh11qQms
   IS83UbL1wMU8sd3GF6Y=
From: "Apotheke" <firewall@studio24mw.com>
[...]
```

Then, trying with command line:

```
# sudo -u test sieve-test -Tlevel=matching -t - /tmp/.dovecot.sieve /tmp/testmail 

      ## Started executing script '.dovecot'
   5: address test
   5:   starting `:contains' match with `i;ascii-casemap' comparator:
   5:   extracting `From' headers from message
   5:   parsing address header value `"Apotheke" <firewall@studio24mw.com>'
   5:   address value `firewall@studio24mw.com'
   5:   extracting `all' part from address <firewall@studio24mw.com>
   5:   matching value `firewall@studio24mw.com'
   5:     with key `Apotheke' => 0
   5:   finishing match with result: not matched
   5: jump if result is false
   5:   jumping to line 7
      ## Finished executing script '.dovecot'


Performed actions:

  (none)

Implicit keep:

 * store message in folder: INBOX

sieve-test(test): Info: final result: success
```

It seems that the test is only performed on the address part but not the full "From" header. I tried all variants in ingo I could think of but just nothing matches.

Is there a way to match the full header line, not just the address?